# Duplicate list names in R

Tags: r, list, dictionary, key

What's going on here when there are duplicate list names in R?

```
l <- list()
l[["A"]] <- 5
l[["B"]] <- 7
l[["C"]] <- 9
names(l) <- c("B", "B", "C")
```

Typing `l[["B"]]` returns

```
$B
[1] 5
```

Typing `l` returns

```
$B
[1] 5

$B
[1] 7

$C
[1] 9
```

Is there a standard way to retrieve all values for the key "B", when "B" is duplicated?

Comment: This is why you really should avoid having duplicate names. Names are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you have duplicate names and you call a subset by name, only the first element is returned. In fact, `[[` will only ever give you one element anyway, so let's look at `[` instead.

```
l["B"]
# $B
# [1] 5
```

We can also see that trying `c("B", "B")` as the subset won't even give us the right result because R goes back and gets the first `B` again.

```
l[c("B", "B")]
# $B
# [1] 5
#
# $B
# [1] 5
```

One of the safest ways to retrieve all the `B` elements is to use a logical subset of the `names()` vector.  This will give us the correct elements.

```
l[names(l) == "B"]
# $B
# [1] 5
#
# $B
# [1] 7
```

This is a great example of why duplicate names should be avoided.