# R: How to handle duplicated entries in lists

Tags: r, xml, duplicates

I have imported a number of XML-files into R, and need to extract some data. However, some of the variables in the output list, extracted using the XML package, are duplicated, and it is not clear to me how to extract data from these entries in a simple way.

The XML-structure:

```
str(data)

List of 2
$ InvoiceLine                :List of 2
..$ ID                 : chr "1"
..$ InvoicedQuantity   :List of 2
$ InvoiceLine                :List of 2
..$ ID                 : chr "2"
..$ InvoicedQuantity   :List of 2
```

If I try to pull out the InvoiceLine-structure I get:

```
str(data$InvoiceLine)

List of 6
$ ID                 : chr "1"
$ InvoicedQuantity   :List of 2
..$ text  : chr "1"
..$ .attrs: Named chr "EA"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "unitCode"
```

That is, I only get information on the first data entry of the name "InvoiceLine". Is there a simple way to get information on each of the "InvoiceLines", or do I have to make a function for sorting this out.

A suggestion could be:

```
# Identifying lines with invoice data
InvoiceLine_indices <- which(names(data) == "InvoiceLine")         

# Structure of first line with invoice data
str(data[InvoiceLine_indices[1]])

List of 6
$ ID                 : chr "1"
$ InvoicedQuantity   :List of 2
..$ text  : chr "1"
..$ .attrs: Named chr "EA"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "unitCode" 

# Structure of second line with invoice data
str(data[InvoiceLine_indices[2]])

List of 6
$ ID                 : chr "2"
$ InvoicedQuantity   :List of 2
..$ text  : chr "2"
..$ .attrs: Named chr "EA"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "unitCode"
```

This solution doesn't seem very sensible though it works. Can you guys suggest another and more sensible way to extract data from duplicate variable names? The actual data I am working with has a much more complex structure, and there are potentially multiple variables that are duplicated. I don't like the idea of having to run a function on each variable.

Comment: Hmm given `lst <- list(a=1:3, a=11:13)`, isn't `lst[names(lst)=="a"]` easy enough? Though I dunno why `[` just returns one element; I found that a bit odd on occasions, too. BTW: The question does not seem to have much to do with XML, but it's more about subsetting lists (or vectors) with duplicate names. And this topic might have led you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244299/duplicate-list-names-in-r

Comment: Thanks, this solves my issue. I wasn't sure if the problem arose from the XML-format, and I had been working with XML all day, so it probably messed up my brain  I agree, I should have looked at lists instead  Thanks for helping out.