# Change multiple elements in R vector with repeated names

Tags: r, names

Let's say I have a vector with repeated names:

```
x <- c(a=1, b=2, a=3, c=4, c=5, b=1, d=1)
```

I want to lookup and change named elements. If I define

```
ElementsToChange <- c("a","b","c")

ChangeTo <- c(9,8,7)
```

I want to change all the elements named 'a' to 9 all those named 'b' to 8 etc. if I do:

```
x[ElementsToChange] <- ChangeTo
```

This will only change only the first (rather than all) elements.

How do I change all, in a simple and elegant way?

Comment: close to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/q/33244299/3871924

Comment: Another take is `v1 <- setNames(setNames(ChangeTo, ElementsToChange)[names(x)], names(x));v1[is.na(v1)] <- x[is.na(v1)]`

Comment: @Frank I meant "hey, this question can help" ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it using a single `split`* command:

```
split(x, names(x))[ElementsToChange] <- ChangeTo
#x
#a b a c c b d 
#9 8 9 7 7 8 1
```

This first splits the x vector by its names, then subsets all elements that are part of the `ElementsToChange` vector and replaces those values with the `ChangeTo` values.

<sub>* technically, you're using `split<-` here, i.e. assignment on the splitted data. The original vector keeps its structure afterwards.</sub>

Comment: that's a brilliant solution. Never thought you could assign after a split!

Answer (score 4):

I assume you need to retain no matches, which makes it a little less elegant:

```
ifelse(names(x)%in%ElementsToChange,ChangeTo[match(names(x),ElementsToChange)],x)
[1] 9 8 9 7 7 8 1
```

If you want the names back you have to rename the vector.

Comment: Or similarly without ifelse, `m <- match(names(x), ElementsToChange); replace(x, !is.na(m), ChangeTo[na.omit(m)])`

Comment: @Frank, why not: `x[!is.na(m)] <- ChangeTo[na.omit(m)]` instead of the replace?

Comment: @MikeH Yeah. Looking at the code of `replace`, they're essentially the same. `replace`, like `ifelse`, creates a new object, while your way modifies `x` (which is closer to what the OP wants).

Comment: @Frank, I feel like that's the most complete/simple solution so I updated my answer with it. Since you did most of it though feel free to post it and I can revert back to my original (worse) solution.

Answer (score 3):

Named elements work much better when the names are unique, but you could do something like

```
Reduce(function(x, z) {
  x[names(x)==z$k] <- z$v
  x
}, split(data.frame(k=ElementsToChange, v=ChangeTo), seq_along(ChangeTo)), init=x)
# a b a c c b d 
# 9 8 9 7 7 8 1
```

But really it would be easier with proper key/values in a data.frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
dd <- data_frame(k=names(x), v=x)
tt <- data_frame(k=ElementsToChange, newv=ChangeTo)
dd %>% left_join(tt) %>% mutate(v=coalesce(newv, v), newv=NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option which replaces directly with `<-`, credit to @Frank:

```
m <- match(names(x), ElementsToChange)
x[!is.na(m)] <- ChangeTo[na.omit(m)]

x
a b a c c b d 
9 8 9 7 7 8 1
```

Since it replaces it directly, it keeps the names as well. You subset `x` to only the names in `ElementsToChange` and then replace their values with the matched elements in `ChangeTo`

Answer (score 2):

```
ids = match(names(x), ElementsToChange)
replace(x, which(!is.na(ids)), ChangeTo[ids[!is.na(ids)]])
#a b a c c b d 
#9 8 9 7 7 8 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this function and provide your elementsToChange and changeTo vectors to get the changed list.

```
library(dplyr)

change <- function(x, elementsToChange = c("a"), changeTo=c(5)){

  if(length(elementsToChange)!=length(changeTo)) {stop("length of elementsToChange is not equal to changeTo")}
  temp<- tibble(name = names(x), value = x)
  temp.change<- tibble(name = elementsToChange, value = changeTo)
  temp2<-temp%>%left_join(temp.change, by = "name")
  temp2<-within(temp2, {
    value.y[is.na(value.y)]<- value.x[is.na(value.y)]
  })
  ret<-temp2$value.y
  names(ret)<-temp2$name
  return(ret)
}
```