# List with duplicate name values in R. Why does it only show one value and not both?

Tags: r, list

Here is a simple example to illustrate my point :

```
lx <- list(a =1, a=2)
lx[["a"]]
```

> 1

Lets say I have a named list and inside the list two objects have the same name. If you try to simply show the values of those objects with the same name, R will only print the first object and not the second. Why wouldn't R show the second value where `a=2`? Is the above code only evaluating until it is true once and then the operation quits? Could you ever call the second object by its name from this list?

I realize you should never name two objects the same thing in a  list, but sometimes if you inherit code you can come across this issue.

Comment: lx[["a"]] returns a component, not a list.  If it returned all of them it would be returning a list if there were more than one and a component of there were one.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33244373/13513328

Comment: @Waldi thanks for the other post I am going to mark this as a dup